# SQL Server 2008: The target name, "package0.event_file", is invalid, or the object could not be found

Tags: sql-server-2008, extended-events

What can cause the following error?

```
Msg 25623, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
The target name, "package0.event_file", is invalid, or the object could not be found
```

Given the following TSQL:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [CloudMigration]
    ON SERVER 
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file
    (SET
        filename = N'C:\PATH\TO\FILE',
        max_file_size = (2),
        max_rollover_files = (2)
    )
    WITH (
        MAX_MEMORY = 2048 KB,
        EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_MULTIPLE_EVENT_LOSS,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 3 SECONDS,
        MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB,
        MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
        TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
        STARTUP_STATE = OFF
    );
GO
```

The TSQL came from this Microsoft article:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does that command succeed on a SQL Server version later than 2008?

Comment: When I issue `select * from sys.dm_xe_session_targets` on a 2008 server, I only get `ring_buffer`.  On later versions of SQL, I get `event_file` also.

Comment: Yes it works in later versions. And I to get `event_file` on this 2008 R2 server.

Comment: Do you have write permission to that folder to NTService\MSSQLServer, which is what the SQL Server service runs as.??

Comment: Yes.  Permissions verified by  dumping a back up to the same folder